# Radio Group not saving correctly

Tags: android, radio-button, save

After a lot of trial and error i decided to ask this question. I cannot save my radio group id, so when i return to the activity which uses radio buttons, all are empty once again.

Here is my code:

```
public class Random extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener {
```

...
...

This is how i commit the checked radio button id

```
public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        int profileGroup_CheckId = profileGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int configGroup_CheckId = configGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        SharedPreferences profileGroupPrefs = getSharedPreferences("profileGroupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = profileGroupPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putInt("profileGroup_CheckId", profileGroup_CheckId);
        prefsEditor.putInt("configGroup_CheckId", configGroup_CheckId);
        prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

and I have added this in onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences profileGroupPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("profileGroupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    profileGroupPrefs.getInt("profileGroup_CheckId", 0);
    profileGroupPrefs.getInt("configGroup_CheckId", 0);
```

Now, from the values ARE being saved inside shared_prefs of my app, since i have checked the profileGroup.xml, but the Radio Buttons are not checked once i return.

I have tried many other ways listed by users here, but none have worked. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set them back once you return to this activity with the values you have saved onResume()/onCreate()???? I don't see where you set them taking values from the sharedpreferences.

Comment: I'm sorry, i pasted the wrong bit of code. I edited my answer. Look again what i have under onCreate

Comment: ("profileGroupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE) Why readable not writable? where is onResume() ? and usually you save your instance state in onPause()

Comment: I had no onResume() or onPause(). I am commiting here: public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId). i need to check the id so i need it to be saved then.

Comment: onResume() will restore your state this is where  you read your SharedPreferences and you set MODE_WORLD_READABLE when you store your preferences look carefully.

Comment: i have switched both mode_world TO WRITEABLE, created an onResume(): http://pastie.org/3257464   Still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one.

```
public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {    
    int profileGroup_CheckId = profileGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int configGroup_CheckId = configGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    SharedPreferences profileGroupPrefs = getSharedPreferences("profileGroupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = profileGroupPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt("profileGroup_CheckId", profileGroup_CheckId);
    prefsEditor.putInt("configGroup_CheckId", configGroup_CheckId);
    prefsEditor.commit();
)

public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
SharedPreferences profileGroupPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("profileGroupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    int a=  profileGroupPrefs.getInt("profileGroup_CheckId", 0);
    int b=  profileGroupPrefs.getInt("configGroup_CheckId", 0);
     profileGroup.check(a); 
     configGroup.check(b);
    }
```

Comment: Oh my lord :D Thank you so much both of you. Im new to Java as you might have guessed :D. This works wonderfully. Thank you both, again.